# FreeTDS on Mac fails from lack of GSS support?

Tags: sql-server, macos, freetds

I'm trying to use FreeTDS on Mac, but I can't connect to my Sql Server. Here's the error:

```
~ chris$ brew install freetds
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/freetds-0.95.80.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/freetds-0.95.80.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring freetds-0.95.80.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.80: 2,820 files, 19.8M
~ chris$ tsql -H <server> -p 1433
log.c:167:Starting log file for FreeTDS 0.95.80
  on 2016-04-20 11:25:20 with debug flags 0x4fff.
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:328:tds_iconv_open(0x7fa843403a20, UTF-8)
iconv.c:187:local name for ISO-8859-1 is ISO-8859-1
iconv.c:187:local name for UTF-8 is UTF-8
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2LE is UCS-2LE
iconv.c:187:local name for UCS-2BE is UCS-2BE
iconv.c:346:setting up conversions for client charset "UTF-8"
iconv.c:348:preparing iconv for "UTF-8" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:395:preparing iconv for "ISO-8859-1" <-> "UCS-2LE" conversion
iconv.c:400:tds_iconv_open: done
net.c:202:Connecting to <server> port 1433 (TDS version 7.0)
net.c:275:tds_open_socket: connect(2) returned "Operation now in progress"
net.c:314:tds_open_socket() succeeded
login.c:804:requested GSS authentication but not compiled in
login.c:472:login packet rejected
query.c:3772:tds_disconnect()
util.c:165:Changed query state from IDLE to DEAD
util.c:322:tdserror(0x7fa8434038e0, 0x7fa843403a20, 20002, 0)
Error 20002 (severity 9):
  Adaptive Server connection failed
util.c:352:tdserror: client library returned TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
util.c:375:tdserror: returning TDS_INT_CANCEL(2)
mem.c:648:tds_free_all_results()
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

How can I enable GSS authentication?

Comment: Have you enabled Kerberos on your Mac? http://www.freetds.org/userguide/kerberos.htm

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to supply a username and password when logging in

```
sql -H <hostname> -U "name" -P "password"
```

Also check your TDS version. 7.0 is used for Microsoft SQL Server 7.0. See the [version guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm).